# How can i read geotags in jpeg?

Tags: software-recommendation, exif

I have JPEG files made by Nikkon camera with geotags in them. I have confirmed that when i upload these images to the social media or mediawiki they show their geolocation tags. However, when i use tools `exiv2` or similar nothing is printed.

Is there any tool (preferrably console based) that can print and maybe manipulate these tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) should be able to read and write geotags. Here some information about [working with GeoTags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/geotag.html) from the project page.

It is by the way a cli solution.

Install on 16.04 should be easy as:

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Comment: Thanks. I have confirmed that this is what i was looking for. Will accept in 7 minutes (cannot sooner)

Comment: No need to hurry ;)